# Transform JSON Data into a timetable

Tags: javascript, html, json, datatable

I have an API that is a large JSON file from a URL, what I'm attempting to do is create a timetable out of it. I've gotten as far as being able to print certain sections of the JSON file but I can't seem to get it how it needs to be. Here is a sample of the JSON, this is only two days worth of fitness classes:

```
{
"error": 0,
"msg": "Calendar data available",
"data": [
    {
        "daylabel": "Saturday 1st of April 2017",
        "datetime": 1490965200,
        "classdata": [
            {
                "id": "22728",
                "name": "TRX/Kettlebell",
                "leadbyuserid": "1395",
                "startdatetime": "1490985900",
                "enddatetime": "1490988600",
                "bookingtypeid": "88",
                "maxcount": "14",
                "shortname": "TRXK",
                "isactive": "1",
                "isbooked": "1",
                "screentypeid": "2",
                "trainername": "Gianluca Silvestrini",
                "classlabel": "TRX/Kettlebell",
                "displaylabel": "05:45am - 06:30am - Studio 2",
                "trainerlabel": "Trainer: Gianluca Silvestrini",
                "isfull": 0,
                "styledata": "background-color:#008c8c;color:#fff;"
            },
            {
                "id": "21367",
                "name": "Barre",
                "leadbyuserid": "695",
                "startdatetime": "1490988600",
                "enddatetime": "1490991300",
                "bookingtypeid": "6",
                "maxcount": "26",
                "shortname": "BARR",
                "isactive": "1",
                "isbooked": "1",
                "screentypeid": "1",
                "trainername": "Angelique Maslen",
                "classlabel": "Barre",
                "displaylabel": "06:30am - 07:15am - Studio 1",
                "trainerlabel": "Trainer: Angelique Maslen",
                "isfull": 0,
                "styledata": "background-color:#008c8c;color:#fff;"
            },
            {
                "id": "21365",
                "name": "Streamline Body Sculpting™ ",
                "leadbyuserid": "1001",
                "startdatetime": "1490990400",
                "enddatetime": "1490993100",
                "bookingtypeid": "95",
                "maxcount": "18",
                "shortname": "SBS",
                "isactive": "1",
                "isbooked": "1",
                "screentypeid": "2",
                "trainername": "Tim Heasman",
                "classlabel": "Streamline Body Sculpting™ ",
                "displaylabel": "07:00am - 07:45am - Studio 2",
                "trainerlabel": "Trainer: Tim Heasman",
                "isfull": 0,
                "styledata": "background-color:#008c8c;color:#fff;"
            },
            {
                "id": "21366",
                "name": "Small Group Circuit Training",
                "leadbyuserid": "1395",
                "startdatetime": "1490990400",
                "enddatetime": "1490992800",
                "bookingtypeid": "71",
                "maxcount": "14",
                "shortname": "SGCT",
                "isactive": "1",
                "isbooked": "1",
                "screentypeid": "3",
                "trainername": "Gianluca Silvestrini",
                "classlabel": "Small Group Circuit Training",
                "displaylabel": "07:00am - 07:40am - Main Floor",
                "trainerlabel": "Trainer: Gianluca Silvestrini",
                "isfull": 0,
                "styledata": "background-color:#008c8c;color:#fff;"
            },
            {
                "id": "21364",
                "name": "Aerial Foundations",
                "leadbyuserid": "695",
                "startdatetime": "1490992200",
                "enddatetime": "1490994900",
                "bookingtypeid": "108",
                "maxcount": "18",
                "shortname": "AFIT",
                "isactive": "1",
                "isbooked": "1",
                "screentypeid": "1",
                "trainername": "Angelique Maslen",
                "classlabel": "Aerial Foundations",
                "displaylabel": "07:30am - 08:15am - Studio 1",
                "trainerlabel": "Trainer: Angelique Maslen",
                "isfull": 1,
                "styledata": "background-color:#666;color:#fff;"
            },
            {
                "id": "21363",
                "name": "Kettlebell Circuit ",
                "leadbyuserid": "1001",
                "startdatetime": "1490994000",
                "enddatetime": "1490996400",
                "bookingtypeid": "99",
                "maxcount": "18",
                "shortname": "KBL",
                "isactive": "1",
                "isbooked": "1",
                "screentypeid": "3",
                "trainername": "Tim Heasman",
                "classlabel": "Kettlebell Circuit ",
                "displaylabel": "08:00am - 08:40am - Main Floor",
                "trainerlabel": "Trainer: Tim Heasman",
                "isfull": 0,
                "styledata": "background-color:#008c8c;color:#fff;"
            },
            {
                "id": "21362",
                "name": "Mat Pilates",
                "leadbyuserid": "1373",
                "startdatetime": "1490994900",
                "enddatetime": "1490997600",
                "bookingtypeid": "89",
                "maxcount": "18",
                "shortname": "MATP",
                "isactive": "1",
                "isbooked": "1",
                "screentypeid": "2",
                "trainername": "Kylie Tabrett",
                "classlabel": "Mat Pilates",
                "displaylabel": "08:15am - 09:00am - Studio 2",
                "trainerlabel": "Trainer: Kylie Tabrett",
                "isfull": 0,
                "styledata": "background-color:#008c8c;color:#fff;"
            },
            {
                "id": "21361",
                "name": "TRX/Pilates",
                "leadbyuserid": "16",
                "startdatetime": "1490995800",
                "enddatetime": "1490998500",
                "bookingtypeid": "97",
                "maxcount": "20",
                "shortname": "TRXP",
                "isactive": "1",
                "isbooked": "1",
                "screentypeid": "1",
                "trainername": "John Rahme",
                "classlabel": "TRX/Pilates",
                "displaylabel": "08:30am - 09:15am - Studio 1",
                "trainerlabel": "Trainer: John Rahme",
                "isfull": 0,
                "styledata": "background-color:#008c8c;color:#fff;"
            },
            {
                "id": "21360",
                "name": "Small Group Cardio",
                "leadbyuserid": "15",
                "startdatetime": "1490997000",
                "enddatetime": "1490999400",
                "bookingtypeid": "100",
                "maxcount": "14",
                "shortname": "SMGC",
                "isactive": "1",
                "isbooked": "1",
                "screentypeid": "3",
                "trainername": "Lyndsay Flight",
                "classlabel": "Small Group Cardio",
                "displaylabel": "08:50am - 09:30am - Main Floor",
                "trainerlabel": "Trainer: Lyndsay Flight",
                "isfull": 0,
                "styledata": "background-color:#008c8c;color:#fff;"
            },
            {
                "id": "26080",
                "name": "40 Day Focus Measurements",
                "leadbyuserid": "16",
                "startdatetime": "1490997600",
                "enddatetime": "1491000900",
                "bookingtypeid": "124",
                "maxcount": "20",
                "shortname": "MEAS",
                "isactive": "1",
                "isbooked": "1",
                "screentypeid": "0",
                "trainername": "John Rahme",
                "classlabel": "40 Day Focus Measurements",
                "displaylabel": "09:00am - 09:55am",
                "trainerlabel": "Trainer: John Rahme",
                "isfull": 0,
                "styledata": "background-color:#008c8c;color:#fff;"
            },
            {
                "id": "21359",
                "name": "Restorative Yoga",
                "leadbyuserid": "1094",
                "startdatetime": "1490998500",
                "enddatetime": "1491002100",
                "bookingtypeid": "84",
                "maxcount": "20",
                "shortname": "RSYO",
                "isactive": "1",
                "isbooked": "1",
                "screentypeid": "2",
                "trainername": "Jennifer Vo",
                "classlabel": "Restorative Yoga",
                "displaylabel": "09:15am - 10:15am - Studio 2",
                "trainerlabel": "Trainer: Jennifer Vo",
                "isfull": 0,
                "styledata": "background-color:#008c8c;color:#fff;"
            },
            {
                "id": "21357",
                "name": "Barre",
                "leadbyuserid": "15",
                "startdatetime": "1491000300",
                "enddatetime": "1491003000",
                "bookingtypeid": "6",
                "maxcount": "26",
                "shortname": "BARR",
                "isactive": "1",
                "isbooked": "1",
                "screentypeid": "1",
                "trainername": "Lyndsay Flight",
                "classlabel": "Barre",
                "displaylabel": "09:45am - 10:30am - Studio 1",
                "trainerlabel": "Trainer: Lyndsay Flight",
                "isfull": 0,
                "styledata": "background-color:#008c8c;color:#fff;"
            },
            {
                "id": "21358",
                "name": "Mat Pilates",
                "leadbyuserid": "1373",
                "startdatetime": "1491000300",
                "enddatetime": "1491003000",
                "bookingtypeid": "119",
                "maxcount": "12",
                "shortname": "MATP",
                "isactive": "1",
                "isbooked": "1",
                "screentypeid": "3",
                "trainername": "Kylie Tabrett",
                "classlabel": "Mat Pilates",
                "displaylabel": "09:45am - 10:30am - Main Floor",
                "trainerlabel": "Trainer: Kylie Tabrett",
                "isfull": 0,
                "styledata": "background-color:#008c8c;color:#fff;"
            },
            {
                "id": "21356",
                "name": "TRX/Pilates Studio 2",
                "leadbyuserid": "1395",
                "startdatetime": "1491003000",
                "enddatetime": "1491005700",
                "bookingtypeid": "98",
                "maxcount": "14",
                "shortname": "TRXP",
                "isactive": "1",
                "isbooked": "1",
                "screentypeid": "2",
                "trainername": "Gianluca Silvestrini",
                "classlabel": "TRX/Pilates Studio 2",
                "displaylabel": "10:30am - 11:15am - Studio 2",
                "trainerlabel": "Trainer: Gianluca Silvestrini",
                "isfull": 0,
                "styledata": "background-color:#008c8c;color:#fff;"
            },
            {
                "id": "21354",
                "name": "Streamline Body Sculpting™",
                "leadbyuserid": "1001",
                "startdatetime": "1491003900",
                "enddatetime": "1491006600",
                "bookingtypeid": "68",
                "maxcount": "28",
                "shortname": "SBS",
                "isactive": "1",
                "isbooked": "1",
                "screentypeid": "3",
                "trainername": "Tim Heasman",
                "classlabel": "Streamline Body Sculpting™",
                "displaylabel": "10:45am - 11:30am - Main Floor",
                "trainerlabel": "Trainer: Tim Heasman",
                "isfull": 0,
                "styledata": "background-color:#008c8c;color:#fff;"
            },
            {
                "id": "27553",
                "name": "Detox Launch Seminar",
                "leadbyuserid": "16",
                "startdatetime": "1491004800",
                "enddatetime": "1491008100",
                "bookingtypeid": "127",
                "maxcount": "50",
                "shortname": "DTOX",
                "isactive": "1",
                "isbooked": "1",
                "screentypeid": "1",
                "trainername": "John Rahme",
                "classlabel": "Detox Launch Seminar",
                "displaylabel": "11:00am - 11:55am - Studio 1",
                "trainerlabel": "Trainer: John Rahme",
                "isfull": 0,
                "styledata": "background-color:#008c8c;color:#fff;"
            },
            {
                "id": "24513",
                "name": "Gentle Flow Yoga",
                "leadbyuserid": "921",
                "startdatetime": "1491006600",
                "enddatetime": "1491010200",
                "bookingtypeid": "92",
                "maxcount": "20",
                "shortname": "GFYO",
                "isactive": "1",
                "isbooked": "1",
                "screentypeid": "2",
                "trainername": "Denise Sorrell",
                "classlabel": "Gentle Flow Yoga",
                "displaylabel": "11:30am - 12:30pm - Studio 2",
                "trainerlabel": "Trainer: Denise Sorrell",
                "isfull": 0,
                "styledata": "background-color:#008c8c;color:#fff;"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "daylabel": "Sunday 2nd of April 2017",
        "datetime": 1491051600,
        "classdata": [
            {
                "id": "21352",
                "name": "Barre",
                "leadbyuserid": "885",
                "startdatetime": "1491080400",
                "enddatetime": "1491083100",
                "bookingtypeid": "6",
                "maxcount": "26",
                "shortname": "BARR",
                "isactive": "1",
                "isbooked": "1",
                "screentypeid": "1",
                "trainername": "Anna McLeod",
                "classlabel": "Barre",
                "displaylabel": "07:00am - 07:45am - Studio 1",
                "trainerlabel": "Trainer: Anna McLeod",
                "isfull": 0,
                "styledata": "background-color:#008c8c;color:#fff;"
            },
            {
                "id": "21351",
                "name": "Flow Yoga",
                "leadbyuserid": "921",
                "startdatetime": "1491081300",
                "enddatetime": "1491084900",
                "bookingtypeid": "81",
                "maxcount": "20",
                "shortname": "FYO",
                "isactive": "1",
                "isbooked": "1",
                "screentypeid": "2",
                "trainername": "Denise Sorrell",
                "classlabel": "Flow Yoga",
                "displaylabel": "07:15am - 08:15am - Studio 2",
                "trainerlabel": "Trainer: Denise Sorrell",
                "isfull": 0,
                "styledata": "background-color:#008c8c;color:#fff;"
            },
            {
                "id": "21350",
                "name": "Streamline Body Sculpting™",
                "leadbyuserid": "1342",
                "startdatetime": "1491084000",
                "enddatetime": "1491086700",
                "bookingtypeid": "68",
                "maxcount": "28",
                "shortname": "SBS",
                "isactive": "1",
                "isbooked": "1",
                "screentypeid": "1",
                "trainername": "Rebecca Pearsall",
                "classlabel": "Streamline Body Sculpting™",
                "displaylabel": "08:00am - 08:45am - Studio 1",
                "trainerlabel": "Trainer: Rebecca Pearsall",
                "isfull": 0,
                "styledata": "background-color:#008c8c;color:#fff;"
            },
            {
                "id": "21349",
                "name": "Mat Pilates",
                "leadbyuserid": "885",
                "startdatetime": "1491084000",
                "enddatetime": "1491086700",
                "bookingtypeid": "119",
                "maxcount": "12",
                "shortname": "MATP",
                "isactive": "1",
                "isbooked": "1",
                "screentypeid": "3",
                "trainername": "Anna McLeod",
                "classlabel": "Mat Pilates",
                "displaylabel": "08:00am - 08:45am - Main Floor",
                "trainerlabel": "Trainer: Anna McLeod",
                "isfull": 0,
                "styledata": "background-color:#008c8c;color:#fff;"
            },
            {
                "id": "21348",
                "name": "Restorative Yoga",
                "leadbyuserid": "921",
                "startdatetime": "1491085800",
                "enddatetime": "1491089400",
                "bookingtypeid": "84",
                "maxcount": "20",
                "shortname": "RSYO",
                "isactive": "1",
                "isbooked": "1",
                "screentypeid": "2",
                "trainername": "Denise Sorrell",
                "classlabel": "Restorative Yoga",
                "displaylabel": "08:30am - 09:30am - Studio 2",
                "trainerlabel": "Trainer: Denise Sorrell",
                "isfull": 0,
                "styledata": "background-color:#008c8c;color:#fff;"
            },
            {
                "id": "21347",
                "name": "Small Group Circuit Training",
                "leadbyuserid": "1342",
                "startdatetime": "1491087600",
                "enddatetime": "1491090000",
                "bookingtypeid": "71",
                "maxcount": "14",
                "shortname": "SGCT",
                "isactive": "1",
                "isbooked": "1",
                "screentypeid": "3",
                "trainername": "Rebecca Pearsall",
                "classlabel": "Small Group Circuit Training",
                "displaylabel": "09:00am - 09:40am - Main Floor",
                "trainerlabel": "Trainer: Rebecca Pearsall",
                "isfull": 0,
                "styledata": "background-color:#008c8c;color:#fff;"
            },
            {
                "id": "21346",
                "name": "Barre",
                "leadbyuserid": "885",
                "startdatetime": "1491087600",
                "enddatetime": "1491090300",
                "bookingtypeid": "6",
                "maxcount": "26",
                "shortname": "BARR",
                "isactive": "1",
                "isbooked": "1",
                "screentypeid": "1",
                "trainername": "Anna McLeod",
                "classlabel": "Barre",
                "displaylabel": "09:00am - 09:45am - Studio 1",
                "trainerlabel": "Trainer: Anna McLeod",
                "isfull": 0,
                "styledata": "background-color:#008c8c;color:#fff;"
            },
            {
                "id": "21345",
                "name": "Aerial Pilates ",
                "leadbyuserid": "1036",
                "startdatetime": "1491090600",
                "enddatetime": "1491093000",
                "bookingtypeid": "101",
                "maxcount": "11",
                "shortname": "APIL",
                "isactive": "1",
                "isbooked": "1",
                "screentypeid": "2",
                "trainername": "Tanya Watts",
                "classlabel": "Aerial Pilates ",
                "displaylabel": "09:50am - 10:30am - Studio 2",
                "trainerlabel": "Trainer: Tanya Watts",
                "isfull": 0,
                "styledata": "background-color:#008c8c;color:#fff;"
            },
            {
                "id": "21344",
                "name": "Semi-Private Kettlebell Circuit",
                "leadbyuserid": "1342",
                "startdatetime": "1491091200",
                "enddatetime": "1491093600",
                "bookingtypeid": "96",
                "maxcount": "14",
                "shortname": "SEMK",
                "isactive": "1",
                "isbooked": "1",
                "screentypeid": "3",
                "trainername": "Rebecca Pearsall",
                "classlabel": "Semi-Private Kettlebell Circuit",
                "displaylabel": "10:00am - 10:40am - Main Floor",
                "trainerlabel": "Trainer: Rebecca Pearsall",
                "isfull": 0,
                "styledata": "background-color:#008c8c;color:#fff;"
            },
            {
                "id": "21343",
                "name": "Mat Pilates ",
                "leadbyuserid": "885",
                "startdatetime": "1491091200",
                "enddatetime": "1491093900",
                "bookingtypeid": "2",
                "maxcount": "36",
                "shortname": "MATP",
                "isactive": "1",
                "isbooked": "1",
                "screentypeid": "1",
                "trainername": "Anna McLeod",
                "classlabel": "Mat Pilates ",
                "displaylabel": "10:00am - 10:45am - Studio 1",
                "trainerlabel": "Trainer: Anna McLeod",
                "isfull": 0,
                "styledata": "background-color:#008c8c;color:#fff;"
            },
            {
                "id": "21342",
                "name": "Aerial Yoga",
                "leadbyuserid": "1036",
                "startdatetime": "1491093900",
                "enddatetime": "1491096900",
                "bookingtypeid": "90",
                "maxcount": "11",
                "shortname": "AYO",
                "isactive": "1",
                "isbooked": "1",
                "screentypeid": "2",
                "trainername": "Tanya Watts",
                "classlabel": "Aerial Yoga",
                "displaylabel": "10:45am - 11:35am - Studio 2",
                "trainerlabel": "Trainer: Tanya Watts",
                "isfull": 1,
                "styledata": "background-color:#666;color:#fff;"
            },
            {
                "id": "21341",
                "name": "Small Group Circuit Training",
                "leadbyuserid": "1342",
                "startdatetime": "1491094800",
                "enddatetime": "1491097200",
                "bookingtypeid": "71",
                "maxcount": "14",
                "shortname": "SGCT",
                "isactive": "1",
                "isbooked": "1",
                "screentypeid": "3",
                "trainername": "Rebecca Pearsall",
                "classlabel": "Small Group Circuit Training",
                "displaylabel": "11:00am - 11:40am - Main Floor",
                "trainerlabel": "Trainer: Rebecca Pearsall",
                "isfull": 0,
                "styledata": "background-color:#008c8c;color:#fff;"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

I need to make it so the dayLabel object become a column with all the classes below it, just like this: http://quanticalabs.com/script/timetable-responsive-schedule-for-wordpress/7010836

Any help in the getting access to the nested objects and creating the correct loop and spitting them out in this way would be great, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To get access to `data` Array you can try to extract it and then iterate with a foreach loop.

```
var jsondata = json.data
```

Then during foreach loop create a div with your `dayLabel` text. And a new foreach working to get classdata inside a list.

PS: Sorry for my english, it's not my native language.